# Oracle linux 7 several nics, request from another subnets, disable rp_filter does not fix it

Tags: linux, linux-networking

Network architecture in brief:

[image: Quickly modeled schema]

Periodically I got network problem with LAN interface in the datacenter, and I decided to make failover: send trafic by upstream - first by old LAN and second through external(from frontend WAN to backend WAN), but second got problem with rp_filter.

I made test stand in the VBOX to model that problem.

On picture you can see VM and their IPs.

I got problem with rp_filter setting. According https://access.redhat.com/solutions/53031 When I set it to 0:

```
root@OL71 motceiadmin]# sysctl -a | grep rp_filter
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp0s10.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp0s10.rp_filter = 0
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.all.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.default.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.enp0s10.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.enp0s3.stable_secret"
net.ipv4.conf.enp0s3.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp0s3.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp0s8.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.enp0s8.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.arp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.rp_filter = 0
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.enp0s8.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.lo.stable_secret"
```

nothing changed!

example from VM2:

```
root@OL72 motceiadmin]# wget http://192.168.56.20
--2024-03-25 05:35:19--  http://192.168.56.20/
Connecting to 192.168.56.20:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 774 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

100%[==============================================================================>] 774         --.-K/s   in 0s

2024-03-25 05:35:19 (102 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [774/774]

[root@OL72 motceiadmin]# wget http://192.168.146.40
--2024-03-25 05:35:35--  http://192.168.146.40/
Connecting to 192.168.146.40:80...
```

wget locks on connecting...

May be I should set something else on the VM1?

On VM3:

```
root@OL73 motceiadmin]# wget http://192.168.252.20
--2024-03-25 05:36:30--  http://192.168.252.20/
Connecting to 192.168.252.20:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 774 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

100%[==============================================================================>] 774         --.-K/s   in 0s

2024-03-25 05:36:30 (108 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [774/774]

[root@OL73 motceiadmin]# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp0s10 enp0s3 enp0s8 enp0s9
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: port=80:proto=tcp:toport=80:toaddr=192.168.252.20
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text, [here](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6480/pictures-of-text-acceptable-or-not/6481#6481) it's as unpopular (and with good reasons!) as on [stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Have you even read the Redhat article?

Comment: Pics to text - done. Yes read, but nothing changed!